# Is there a way do define a context for a group of commands in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

`jQuery.proxy()` has some of the features I'm looking for, but ideallyI would like to be able to do something like:

```
$('#some-id').context(function(){
    $('.some-class').show();
    $('li').css('background','red');
});
```

The effect of which would be the same as:

```
$('#some-id .some-class').show();
$('#some-id li').css('background','red');
```

Does jQuery have a method like my `context` above?

Comment: Why do you want to turn 2 lines of code to be 4 lines?

Comment: For easier organization of code and simpler reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get to that is defining the context in your `jQuery` call:

```
var $el = $('#some-id');
$('.some-class', $el).show();
$('li', $el).css('background','red');
```

- [jQuery Selector Context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context)

You could also use chaining:

```
$('#some-id')
    .find('.some-class').show().end()
    .find('li').css('background','red');
```

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

**In both cases,** the improvement would be that you only query the DOM once for the initial selector (`'#some-id'` in this case).

Comment: note that this only works on the main `$()` method - it doesn't work on other jQuery methods such as `.append()`.

Comment: @Alnitak Right, that's why I wrote `jQuery` call in the beginning (`$` is a shortcut for that).

Comment: that wasn't my point - you can't do `$(foo).appendTo(parent, context)`, for example.

Comment: @Alnitak We are saying the same thing.

Comment: Hm, I have forgot about the chaining (or, specifically, I have forgot about the `end()` method, as I have tried without it and failed. This is pretty much what I had in mind, so I'll mark this as the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called context but it will return the context. In jQuery if you want to set the context then you can pass it to jQuery selector optionally as a second parameter. Here is an example `jQuery( selector [ , context ]  )` and you can use it like this `$("input:radio", document.forms[0]);`

To know more about passing context http://api.jquery.com/context/

For more information about retrieving context Please refer http://api.jquery.com/context/